# Office 365 Development Production Setup

Tags: content-deployment, office-365

We are seeking advice here on what the development, integration and production environments are setup as for a development team.

We are currently trying to migrate code from development to an integration environment and then to production. In the development environment we have

1. Custom Site Pages with web parts based on custom page layouts
2. Custom Lists
3. Custom content types
4. Custom Page layouts
5. List item
6. Page content
7. Custom masterpages
8. Apps

For an on prem SharePoint 2013 environment we could use PowerShell to do a custom deployment however we are using Office 365.

With Office 365, how would we move all this content using a build script if this is at all possible?

Comment: Are you talking about sharepoint onpremise to Sharepoint online migration?

Comment: Hi Aanchal sharepoint online migration to sharepoint online migration. Both the dev site and the integration and production.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand your problem, you need to package all your components in single solution. i.e in a wsp (You have to create a Sandbox solution for this) or you can use sharepoint app to package all your components.

In this way you can easily move your contents or customization to another server.

You can also check the following links to migrate your data:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_cloud/archive/2012/03/11/migrating-content-between-sharepoint-online-site-collections.aspx

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/27107.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2011/10/10/how-to-back-up-office-365-sharepoint-online-data.aspx